# Compress multiple images using Kmeans Clustering

Tags: python, k-means, image-compression

My error:

```
  File "C:/Users/hero/PycharmProjects/project/CompressMe.py", line 14, in 

<module>
    image = image.reshape(image.shape[0] * image.shape[1], image.shape[2])
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I am trying to compress multiple images present in a folder using K-means Algorithm. But, I got a memory error, So I used MiniBatchKMeans but, again I am getting an IndexError.

```
 import os
from skimage import io
from sklearn.cluster import  MiniBatchKMeans
import numpy as np

algorithm = "full"
for f in os.listdir('.'):
    if f.endswith('.png'):
        image = io.imread(f)
        rows = image.shape[0]
        cols = image.shape[1]

        image = image.reshape(image.shape[0] * image.shape[1], image.shape[2])
        kmeans = MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=128, n_init=10, max_iter=200)
        kmeans.fit(image)

        clusters = np.asarray(kmeans.cluster_centers_, dtype=np.uint8)
        labels = np.asarray(kmeans.labels_, dtype=np.uint8)
        labels = labels.reshape(rows, cols);

        #  np.save('codebook'+f+'.npy', clusters)
        io.imsave('compressed_' + f + '.png', labels);
```

Comment: I was able to run your code without any errors. The only modification I made was to replace `for f in os.listdir('.'):` loop and instead use a single image path. Can you recheck your code and see if the error persists for a single image path?

Comment: I want to compress multiple images present in a folder So, I used the for  loop. This code works without error for a single image.

Comment: Just tested it for multiple files, it still works. Only addition was that I used `os.chdir()` to change working directory to my test folder. The only mistake in your code posted here was that of indentation, which I'm sure was accidental. The problem does not seem to be in this piece of code atleast. Perhaps try it on some different test images?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of the png format is that different png files can have a different number of channels (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#Pixel_format). In case you're dealing with grayscale images, `io.imread` will return a 2-D image (see the documentation: http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io.html#skimage.io.imread)

Probably try asserting that the dimensionality of your image is always 3, using the following:

```
image = io.imread(f)
if len(image.shape) == 2: # image is grayscale
    image = image[:,:,np.newaxis] # Expand to a third dimension
```

Comment: Might want to link to the documentation of skimage to show that it will indeed `imread()` a grayscale image as 2D. It will, but other libs (e.g. OpenCV) will not do this by default, so it would be good to add into your answer. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Done. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for contributing! Hope to see you around more!